# Java EE: how to get the URL of my application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In Java EE, how can I dynamically retrieve the full URL for my application?

For example, if the URL is `"localhost:8080/myapplication/"`, I would like a method that can simply return this to me, either as a String or something else.

I am running GlassFish as application server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside any servlet or filter you have access to `HttpServletRequest` which allows you to see what URL was used by the client to access your application, e.g. try [`HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()).

Comment: Great! However, can this also be done from inside an ordinary backing bean?

Comment: and if you're using JSF, you can find this (HttpServletRequest object) in the current instance of FacesContext

Answer (score 0):

In JSF I was able to achieve this relatively easily using the following helper function (all you need is a reference to the `HttpServletRequest`:

```
public static String getRequestUrl() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
    if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
        requestURL.append("?");
        requestURL.append(request.getQueryString());
    }
    return requestURL.toString();
}
```